Как изменить фото в сообщении? python aiogram 3.3
Есть код:
@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def start(message: Message):
    await db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
    photo = FSInputFile("pic1.jpg")
    message_text = "hi"
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, caption = message_text, photo=photo,
reply_markup=keyboard())

Как можно изменить фото в этом сообщении при нажатии на кнопку клавиатуры?

Ответ вас удивит — он есть в документации ;)
В вашем случае:
@dp.callback_query(F.data == 'some_data_from_button')
async def button_pressed(resp: CallbackQuery):
    message_text, photo = "hi again", FSInputFile("pic2.jpg")
    await resp.message.edit_media(InputMediaPhoto(media=photo, caption=message_text), reply_markup=keyboard())

Отпишитесь в комментариях, если не разберётесь с импортами — дополню ответ.

спасибо большое, разобрался. Немного не по теме - resp: CallbackQuery, не встречал. Всегда писал callback_query: CallbackQuery, как в связи с этим поменяется последняя строчка? message_id=callback_query.message.message_id добавляю - выдает ошибку message не найдено
